# Uploading multiple APK app with google play api using fastlane supply

Tags: android, fastlane, google-play-developer-api

While setting up a continuous deploy pipeline for our mobile projects I ran into an error while uploading an APK (signed and aligned) to the play store through google's API.

I'm using fastlane's supply action to do the actual upload (which uses google's ruby api client).

The first upload of APK with version x on the alpha track was successful.

The second upload of the same APK with version y on the alpha track failed with the following message:

> multiApkDowngradedDevice: Devices with version 100144 of this app
>   would be downgraded to version 100142 if they met the following
>   criteria:   [(    API_LEVEL in range 15-0 AND RELEASE_TRACK containing
>   any of each of [[ALPHA]]   AND   SCREENS containing any of each of
>   [[small, normal, large, xlarge]]   AND   NATIVE_PLATFORM containing
>   any of each of [[x86_64 (arm64-v8a)*, x86_64 (armeabi-v7a)*, x86
>   (armeabi-v7a)*]]   AND   FEATURES containing all of
>   [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT,
>   android.hardware.WIFI]    )].

I'm having trouble finding info on this `multiApkDowngradedDevice` error, since the api's documentation doesn't mention any error codes.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Thx,

Bert

Comment: you decremented your version. You need to update the version in /AndroidManifest.xml and build again

Comment: Well, that's the weird part. The version was actually incremented.
Version x (on the alpha track) was 1.0.14, and version y (the new version to replace version x on the alpha track) was version 1.0.15

Comment: did you increase versionCode and versionName?

Comment: @Bert..I also want to upload multiple apk with fastlane supply. Right now, I am able to upload a single apk with fastlane supply. Could you tell me, how to upload multiple apk with fastlane supply?

Comment: Check out my setup for uploading multiple APKs to Beta. Use similar setup. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/8215/fastlane

Comment: Updated link for android docs by @GokhanArik: https://riptutorial.com/android/topic/8215/fastlane